# Set number of angular grid lines to a fixed value for a PolarPlot with jfreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm facing an issue using PolarPlot with jFreeChart. My code plots a single dot with an arbitrary angle and a radius of maximum 1. Everytime I redraw the plot, the number of radial grid lines changes. This makes the program very ugly. [image: Example of different number of grid lines]

How can I constrain the number of lines to a predefined number?

Comment: That controls the wrong lines... I don't need to change the 45° angle between the angle-lines. Please look at the picture I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a satisfying solution:

```
final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPolarChart("", dataset, true, true, false);
final PolarPlot plot = (PolarPlot) chart.getPlot();
((NumberAxis)plot.getAxis()).setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(0.25));
plot.getAxis().setRange(-1, 1);
```

Important is the last line, where you set the Range, else if you only plot one single dot the spacing is *correct*, but the plot will be scaled and the plotted dot lies on the border.